# The UIColor Class does not let me instantiate a UIColor. Has to do with the ? ! symbols

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, uicolor

I am trying to create an instance of an UIColor with the following code:

```
var someColor:UIColor = UIColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
```

The precompiler tells me that there is an error. It says that UIColor! is not convertible to UIColor.

This is one of Swift's biggest mysteries I have not solved.

What does UIColor! mean? More in detail, I do not get why is the exclamation ! sign is there.

I am kinda familiar with ?. What I understand is that it is an optional. If it exists it holds its' value, and if it does not, it is set to NIL.

Any advice and correction is very much appreciated.

Thank you for solving my question.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The method you're using is an *instance* method of UIColour, not a class method. Do you mean this instead:

```
UIColor(white:1.0, alpha:0.3)
```

The method you're using should be called on an existing colour. It's not an initialiser. The error message isn't very helpful, I agree. I think this:

> It says that UIColor! is not convertible to UIColor.

Is Swift attempting to convert the class into an instance.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So am I going to be able to use your color say for some storyboard stuff? for example, set var whiteColor = UIColor(white:1.0, alpha:0.3) and then say assign the whiteColor to a button/label in the storyboard (by writing the appropriate code of course)

Comment: Yes, of course. You'd need an outlet to the label, then just set .textColor or what have you

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of `UIColor` for [colorWithAlphaComponent](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/colorWithAlphaComponent:) it is instance method.So you need to you need to call this on `UIColor` instance.